# HTC One (GSM) Cannot Connect to Ubuntu 14.04 (Android 4.4.3)

Tags: android, htc

I am having trouble with my HTC One (M7 GSM) that won't connect to my Ubuntu laptop.

It shows nothing basically. I plugged it into the USB port and used `lsusb`, but it showed nothing about my Android phone. And I cannot mount it (the option is grayed out on my phone).

How do I get Ubuntu to pick up my phone from USB?

Answer (score 1):

You need to turn on Developer Mode in your settings. To actually activate the developer options you need to do the following steps:

1. got to settings/about/software information/more.
2. From there you will tap on the Build Number 7 times (you will see a countdown to the number of times left to tap)

See [this](http://androidtechy.com/index.php/software/android/83-enable-developer-mode-on-htc-one-running-4-2-2-rom.html) for further information.